# List of acceptable stars for determining the end of shabbat

Tags: shabbat

The week before last I saw the three stars of Orion's belt but the western sky was not completely dark.

Is there a list of acceptable stars (i.e. not exceptionally bright ones) that one can use for determining the end of Shabbat

What position in the sky must they be in?

Comment: All traditions about this have been lost with the advent of clocks and cities, but with some careful calculations you can make a very reasonable guess that any star (not planet) counts https://www.yutorah.org/lectures/1005719

Comment: so why is "medium size" specified?

Comment: To exclude big wandering stars (aka planets)